# PowerShell Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file"

Tags: database, oracle, powershell

I am getting this error in

> PowerShell

I am trying to stablish a connection to an Oracle Database and see if I can get any data in return. I found some code and put this together.  I see most people use the "connection.open() to stablish a connection to the database so that is the norm but I am not sure why I am getting this errors any ideas?

```
    PS SQLSERVER:\>

        Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file"
        At line:8 char:1
        + $connection.open()
        + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OracleException
         
        Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Connection must be open for this operation"
        ..
        ..
        ..
        PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

here is my code

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
$username =  Read-Host -Prompt "Enter database username"
$password =  Read-Host -Prompt "Enter database password"
$datasource = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter database TNS name"
$query = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL"
$connectionString = 'User Id=' + $username + ';Password=' + $password + ';Data Source=' + $datasource
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
$command=$connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText=$query
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()
while ($reader.Read()) {
$reader.GetString(1) + ', ' + $reader.GetString(0)
}
$connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [System.Data.OracleClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) instead of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll. You have to have the Oracle Client installed on the machine you are executing the script.